# I get an error like this: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mymodule' What do I need to do to make this module import work?

Tags: python, module

I have my own python module in a custom location here:

/mydata/python/mylibrary/mymodule.py
for linux, or for Windows:
C:\mydata\python\mylibrary\mymodule.py

There are no other files or folders in the directory “mylibrary”.

When I try and import this module into a python program with the statement:

import mymodule

I get an error like this:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mymodule'

What do I need to do to make this module import work?

need help, tried everything

Comment: did you created an `__init__.py` file for the module?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for/448279#448279

Comment: Where are you running your interpreter from, when you try to import your module? Is `mylibrary` intended to be a package, or is it just an ill-named folder?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.